# How can I make a List Grid View using this code?

Tags: html, css

I tried to edit the css as much as possible besides that in Js I made a small function but it didn't work for me

```
 <div class="row featured portfolio-items">
    <div class="item col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-xs-12 landscapes sale pr-0 pb-0">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately there is too little detail in this question for the community to provide you with any meaningful guidance.  Stack Overflow is best suited for _specific programming questions_ -- I think you need a clear statement of what you need, what you've tried (with code examples) and what is not working.  I would recommend viewing [ask] and seeing if you can reword this question in a manner that enables the community to better assist you.  Good luck!

Comment: Looks like you're using a CSS framework – is it Bootstrap? Also, can you give more detail on the type of list grid view you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to create the Grid layout programmatically using JavaScript/jQuery.

Here is an example you can try:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="mycontainer"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var rowCount = 5;
        var colCount = 3;

        var container = $('#mycontainer');

        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
            var row = $('<div>').addClass('row m-0').appendTo(container);
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++) {
                var col = $('<div>').addClass('col border border-success').text("Col " + colIndex+", Row "+ rowIndex).appendTo(row);
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```